# React: how can I automatically split long texts into multiple <p> tags?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've build a component used on individual team member pages,

```
    {TeamData.map((item, index) => {
  return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="text-3xl xs:text-2xl md:text-3xl lg:text-5xl xl:text-6xl mb-5">{item.name}</h1>
        <p className="text-xl leading-10 uppercase mb-5 text-gray-700">{item.title}</p>
        <p className="text-xl leading-10 mb-5">{item.bio}</p>
        </div>     
  );
})}
```

that is populated with a data structure that looks like this:

```
      {
id: '1',  
link: 'john-doe',
name: 'John Doe',
alt: 'John Doe',
title: 'Managing Director',
bio: 'works with retail and consumer-goods companies to guide growth, commercial and operational transformations'}
```

},

My problem is that long **bio** texts and up as one large **p** tag. I want to have multiple

`<p className="text-xl leading-10 mb-5">{item.bio}</p></div>`

tagss, once a bio text exceeds a specific length, let's say 20 words.

How can I achieve this in React?

Comment: `<p>` is a semantic element. You cannot just

Comment: break the text in a middle of a sentence. See what I mean?

Comment: if you want the text to split for only display purposes, then you can simply do this with CSS. what is the exact use case here?

Comment: @DennoFreezy you're on the correct way just check the length of the string if it's greater then your provided limit so then split n to small chunks or you can use th substring the characters as well.

Answer (score 0):

tag of html is meant for using also for multiple rows, so you don't have to break it into several tags, instead if you specify it's `max-width` property via css, you'll get it broken into multiple lines. This way you can style it as you want, you can play with `white-space` for better UX as you need.